# How to fetch a row of data and store it in an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble fetching data from my database and sorting it in an array.

Here is my current code:

I'm looping through each engine to create a sorted array with each servers ID.

```
for($i=0; $i <= $servers_default_engines_count; $i++){

        //get all servers with this engine type, and get how many
        $query = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `cgshop_servers` WHERE `server_engine` = $i");
        $server_id = mysql_fetch_row($query);

        $server[$i] = array();  
        array_push($server[$i], $server_id); 

    };
```

Result with mysql_fetch_row:

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

also:

```
[0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
```

But i'm looking to return it like this:
() placed for explanation reasons.

```
Array(
   [0] (engine1) => Array(

      [0](server1) => 2 (serverid)
   )
   [1(engine2)] => Array(

      [0](server1) => 1 (serverid)
      [1](server2) => 3 (serverid)
   )
)
```

This is the current data in the mysql tables:
cgshop_servers:

```
id   server_name   server_ip    serevr_port    server_engine    source_engine
1    test1         195.62.14.65 15464          1                1
2    test2         195.62.14.63 15464          0                0
3    test3         195.64.14.62 15465          1                1
```

Comment: What is `$db`?  Is it a `PDO` object?  You shouldn't be mixing `mysql_fetch_row()` and `PDO`; use `$query->fetch()` instead.

Comment: i am writing this for vBulletin, in order to connect to the database the correct way to do it through their product system is to use $db->query() or any other mysql functions.

Answer (score 0):

you are fetching it wrongly, since you said you are using prepared statement, below is the updated code, you can use.

```
$server = array();
for($i=0; $i <= $servers_default_engines_count; $i++){
    //get all servers with this engine type, and get how many
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `cgshop_servers` WHERE `server_engine` = ?");
    $sth->bind_param('i', $i);
    $sth->execute();
    $server[$i] = $sth->fetch();
};
```

or better of you can fetch it with one single query without any loop like this.

```
$totalServerCounts = range(0, $servers_default_engines_count);
$sth = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `cgshop_servers` WHERE `server_engine` IN(".implode(', ', $totalServerCounts).")");
$servers = $sth->fetch_all();
```

Comment: Still get's the same result:

output:

[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

Comment: This gives me a different output every time the loop runs, the array is used for sorting, 0 = disabled 1 = source and so on, then the loop should put the correct servers inside of its its sub array creating something that should look like this -> array( [0] => array( [0] => disabled1, [2] => disabled2,))

Comment: @BExDeath that is not the same, you were getting two hierarchal level array and that is one hierarchal level, since `mysql_fetch_row($query);` will always return an array you will get in that format only. by seeing the new output, it seems to me that this is what you were asking for,

Comment: i'm a little confused on what you are saying but, the update you have me creates an array like this -> [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

still not providing all the servers that are in the database.

Comment: @BExDeath as i already explained, `mysql_fetch_row($query)` will always return an indexed array. there is no way to change that, what you should be doing is, once you have the values in `$server` array, manipulate it the way you want.

Comment: i am unable to read the output correctly in the comment section, can you update in your question and indent it properly.

Comment: I have updated my post to give more explanation on what i am looking for.

Comment: okay, i am updating my answer, on how to manipulate the `$server` array to get desired output after fetching the records.

Comment: it seems you may be missing something as there is only a $ in      `$server[$] = $server_id;`

Comment: yeah, it should be `$i`, i have updated the answer, have a look, and let me know what it outputs now.

Comment: @BExDeath are you using PDO are prepared query?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken it is a prepared query, but there is little documentation on the vBulletin api.

Comment: then you have syntax error, i didn't see it properly sorry for that, i am updating the all of code.

Comment: Both solutions seem to come up blank, with no array data.

Comment: also i am not sure, what vbulletin uses, if it is prepared statement, then the above code should work, if it is PDO, then let me know

Comment: Still nothing, after `$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM cgshop_servers WHERE server_engine = $i");` nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `mysql_fetch_assoc` ([information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php))

> mysql_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row as an associative array

---

**Example Usage**

```
 $mysql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cgshop_servers` WHERE `server_engine` = ?", $i);
 $my_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_query);
 print_r($my_array);
```

Comment: Same thing `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )
)`

But, it works right just it don't pull the third server!

Comment: can you give us a schema of what the `cgshop servers` looks like? fields / data types etc etc.. kind of need to know what we are trying to query.